# Unable to run shell commands in gke pod using yaml file

Tags: kubernetes

If I put this command in the yaml file:

```
command: [ "/bin/sh", "-c", "env" ]
```

it says crashloopbackoff. I am using `FROM java:openjdk-8-jre-alpine` (inside the image). What could be the error?

Basically I am not able to run any command inside the yaml file but which I open pod with the help of `kubectl exec -it ... /bin/sh` I am able to run shell commands.

I want to use configmap. But envFrom is not valid in GKE pods. Is there any alternative?

Comment: `envFrom is not valid in GKE pods`. Is it?

Comment: yes that is one thing and I am not able use Command in yaml files

Comment: Provide your yaml file